# Wordpress - Access shortcode HTML and add Form Validations to stop empty form submission?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I have an issue with my search form I am using the WordPress plugin
IMPress Listings and Search & Filter to show the property listing taxonomies. I have added the shortcode to my home page.

`<?php echo do_shortcode('[searchandfilter submit_label="Search" taxonomies="status,locations,property-types"]');?>`

but when an empty form is submitted **www.domain.co.uk/estateagents/?s=**
this is redirected to the front-page and messes all the CSS up and shows every single post on the site which I do not wont.

I have searched all around google but the answers seem to be 5Years old and no longer seem to work.

The easiest way I can think of is added Form Valuation so they can submit and empty form and get redirected. But because the form is generated by the short code I am unsure how to add classes or IDs to the Form.

This is the form generated:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="searchandfilter">
<div>
    <ul><li><select name='ofstatus' id='ofstatus' class='postform' >
    <option value='0' selected='selected' >All Status</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="9">For Rent</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="19">For Sale</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="32">New</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="23">Pending</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="ofstatus_operator" value="and" /></li><li><select name='oflocations' id='oflocations' class='postform' >
    <option value='0' selected='selected'>All Locations</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="21">Birmingham</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="oflocations_operator" value="and" /></li><li><select name='ofproperty-types' id='ofproperty-types' class='postform' >
    <option value='0' selected='selected'>All Property Types</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="20">Bungalow</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="14">Residential</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="ofproperty-types_operator" value="and" /></li><li><input type="hidden" name="ofsubmitted" value="1">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</li></ul></div>
```

How do I access this if its generated into a shortcode? and how do I add validation so the empty form doesn't get submitted?

Comment: I see two options, first one is to edit the plugin and edit directly de html so you will load your custom form with the validation. Second one, is to add whatever you want to the form (also the validation) with jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, If I was to go for option two I'm not that familiar with jquery do you know anywhere I can find out more details about how to do this?

Comment: You will find all about jQuery here: https://api.jquery.com/, also check this to add Classes: https://api.jquery.com/addclass/. Take care about validating forms via jQuery/javascript. They are not the best solution to do this. It's better to do on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the shortcode form created by plugin (If the form is not going to change)

```
<?php remove_shortcode( 'searchandfilter' );?>
```

now add you ownshortcode with the form in the callback function of the shortcode.

```
    <?php add_shortcode( 'searchandfilter', 'my_search_form' );
    function my_search_form($atts, $content){
    //write you own form here
}
    ?>
```

Validate the form at client side.

Include this js file in header of the page
http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js

put this code below the included JS

```
<script>
$().ready(function() {
  $("#commentform").validate();
});
</script>
```

And apply the ID to your form

```
<form action="" method="post" class="searchandfilter" id="commentform">
```

and make you input boxes required as

```
<input id="cname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required="" aria-required="true">
```

For further details goto this link

http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/radio-checkbox-select-demo.html

Comment: Thanks, My issue is that I don't have direct access to the form as it looks like it is generated by the plugin.

Comment: The form is for an estate agents and will change when new listing have been added :/

Comment: Ok, ao you canfetch the newly added listing in you own shortcode.. or simply copy the HTML inside plugin shortcode (It must be fetching the new listing as well) to yours shortcode and provide ID to the Form.